# Jquery close button works on some divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on this for a while and I cant seem to figure it out. I have a clickable jquery map of the United States that when you click a state it will open up a list of links for that state. I am using the U.S Map plugin (http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/#usage-style-options).

The weird part that I can't figure out is when I click California, the jquery I wrote to use with the plugin works as expected but when you click the other states it does not. I will provide the url of my test site if you want to see for yourself what it is suppose to be doing. First click California and then close the modal window with the X in the corner then try another state and you will see that the close button does not work. California can be opened and closed repeatedly with no problem.

Here is the test url: http://test.sportdirections.com/restaurants.php

Here is my Jquery code

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX-200;
    mouseY = e.pageY-500;
});  

$('#map').usmap({
    // The hover action..
    mouseover: function(event, data){
        $('#restaurant-hover-'+data.name).css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn(500);    
    },

    // Hover away action
    mouseout:function(event, data){
        $('#restaurant-hover-'+data.name).fadeOut('fast');
    },

    // State clicked action
    click:function(event, data) {
        function closeList () {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#links-'+data.name).fadeOut('fast');
        }
        $('#close').click(closeList);
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#links-'+data.name).fadeIn(1000);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the html being generated. Every single popup has the same `input` each with the same id being `close`. This is giving you your problem because you cannot have more than one html element with the same ID.

You are creating the popups with the id `links-STATE`. See if you can do something similar for the close button or use a class then jQuerys find() or parent() selectors to close the popup

Comment: They all have different ids. The ids are #links-CA or replace CA with whatever state is clicked. close is the id of the close button. Am is suppose to name every close button as a different id?

Comment: Yes but you have a close button for each #links-CA and #links-NY ect. And each of those close buttons has the id close. Use the developer tools in chrome or firefox to examine all of the HTML being generated

Comment: Ok thanks I accidently put the close botton in the while loop. thanks for pointing that out.